# how to add header in flutter http request?

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart

I have to make a http request for an api

base url is: https://learning-objects-v2.p.rapidapi.com

```
GET /search-provider?keywords=Python&lang=en&provider=Coursera&sort=popularity&model=strict&max=20&page=2 
X-Rapidapi-Host: learning-objects-v2.p.rapidapi.com
X-Rapidapi-Key: key
Host: learning-objects-v2.p.rapidapi.com
```

what I have tried

```
var client = http.Client();
    var result = null;
    final response = await client.get(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://learning-objects-v2.p.rapidapi.com/search-provider?keywords=$keyword&lang=en&provider=Coursera&sort=popularity&model=strict&max=20&page=2'),
      // Send authorization headers to the backend.
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader:
            'key',
      },
    );
```

but this does not seem to work properly can someone help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': '<Your token>'
   };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
do i have to add Authorization or X-Rapidapi-Key

Comment: thanks brother it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
Client client = Client();

 final baseHeader = {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: getBaseAuth(),
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
 };

 final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('$baseUrl/services/mobile/info'),
        headers: baseHeader);
```